# Problem opening a cloned C++Builder project from GitHub using Git

Tags: git, c++builder

I'm trying to have version control and remote work for my C++Builder project. In order to achieve that, I have installed the last version of Git on my computers (Desktop and Laptop). I made a test project called GitTest and saved it inside a folder named GitTest.

[image: GitTest project]

The project runs as expected:

[image]

Then I started to config the folder using Git bash, as shown in the next images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

After that, I have tried to modify my project adding a `TLabel`, then update and commit, in order to switch between versions and see if it is working as expected:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Performing checkout and reopening the project to see if I have version control:

[image]

[image]

Git as a local version control works good in C++Builder!

As I need a way to use the same project on another computer, for example my laptop, I have created a repository on GitHub to upload my project:

[image]

[image]

Then I can see my files on GitHub!

[image]

Everything is good here.

The problem is, when I go to clone that project on my computer. I make a new folder:

[image]

[image]

When I try to open the project, C++Builder stays frozen:

[image]

I have tried to delete `.cbproj.local` to see if this fixes the problem, but still I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Are you sure this issue is related to git/github?
Did you compare the C++ Builder versions? Did you try to open a local project on your laptop and see if it's freezing?

Comment: I think that the issue is not related to git/github. C++ builder version are not the same on my devices, but I have worked the same project using a USB memory to carry those files and then work on my laptop/desktop, doing on that way I dont hacve problems